# how to pass an array as parameter when making a request to server,iphone

Tags: iphone, nsurlrequest

**Given** :

```
a chunk of books and each book will associated with unique id
```

**Scenario** :

```
user can order more than one book
```

**Goal** :

```
   making an NSMutableURLRequest and send this request to server and let server know which books 
    are being picked
```

**Question** :

```
  For example, user A will choose 3 books whose id are a, b ,c. How can I send an array 
  containing with these id in the request so that server can know that user A are ordering these books
```

Comment: json would be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the format your server is expecting, IF for example you use RESTful then you would have to chose between post or get and based on that build your query. If you do use restful then use RestKit API and use the params property. (or you can build them urself directly with the basic ios api). You can send your data in JSON format as well but the server would have to know how to parse it.

Comment: we are using Restfull and it is post request. The server side wants me to pass an array of books'id as one of params. I am using AFNetworking API to make and send a request to server. But I am still stuck how to send the array of id to them....

Comment: you cannot send "an array" per se, if the server expects a JSON format then you first convert your array into JSON and send that as the value for key "books" for example. (JSON is just a format which is a bunch of text that servers can read and parse to build the array themselves)